# Issue with Radio Button using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium unable to locate element. Trying to navigate through a website that forces you to select certain elements as you go in order to define the final request. I am not sure, but from what I have found already on here the fact that the button is of Radio type may be important.

Here is the part of my code that works so far in order to launch driver, click past cookies, resize and scroll the page so that the element is visible. I do not believe that the resize and scroll is necessary from what I understand of finding elements by Xpath, but I did it anyway to eliminate possible causes for issue.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Key
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://www.valencia.es/es/cas/atencion-ciudadana/comunicar-una-incidencia" 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
time.sleep(1)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

Cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[1]")
Cookies.click()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 1000)")
```

This is the element that I am trying to find:

```
<input type="radio" name="Grupo" value="GCOM-001" onclick="javascript: submit();">
```

And here is the code for my attempt to click with Xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@type='radio' and @value='GCOM-001']").click()
```

And my attempt using CSS_Selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='GCOM-001']").click()
```

I am unable to find the element using either of these two methods (nor numerous other previous iterations). In both cases this is the returned error.

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: in case it matters, I am working on a Mac with OS13.1 and an M1 chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to find the element simply because it is not present in the HTML of the page loaded by selenium. In fact if you run `'GCOM-001' in driver.page_source` it prints `False`. This usually happens when there is an iframe in the page, hiding its content.

[image]

To access it we must first switch to it, using its id

```
driver.switch_to.frame('iframe_nsf')
```

Now `'GCOM-001' in driver.page_source` prints `True` so we can finally click the button

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value=GCOM-001]').click()
```

p.s. I suggest to use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iframe_nsf")))
```

rather than `driver.switch_to.frame('iframe_nsf')`, because it waits (up to 20 seconds) to see if the iframe gets loaded in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The *value* i.e. `GCOM-001` are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

As per the HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="Grupo" value="GCOM-001" onclick="javascript: submit();">
```

To click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Grupo'][onclick*='submit']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Grupo' and contains(@onclick, 'submit')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='Grupo'][onclick*='submit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Grupo' and contains(@onclick, 'submit')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work either. Even scrolling to the bottom of the page and/or waiting does not seem to make this button visible to Selenium even though it is clearly visible for human users to click and to inspect.

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: Same as before.